# Facebook debugger can't find my og:image

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Facebook can't seem to find the value I pass in meta og:image.

The url is: https://glouton.ca

And the debugger, even after I do recollect, I still have a warning.

```
The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

What am I doing wrong? I feel like it worked last week...

Comment: Some earlier `meta` tags aren't self-closed. Maybe this is related ?

Comment: @Protectator I just corrected, to no result. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current tags are valid. The problem is caching, either on their side, on yours or one somewhere in between, because they aren't getting the current version of your site.

I also inspected your page in the Facebook debugger, and found that they're using an outdated version of your page. The result they're collecting for your link is available here : (The link to access this is present around the bottom of the debugger page)

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fglouton.ca%2F

At the time of writing this message, the code looks like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
<p>tyle="height:100%"&gt;

</p>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics --><script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-109094225-1"></script><script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'UA-109094225-1');
    </script><meta name="description" content="Glouton est un moteur de recherche intelligent qui permet de trouver des recettes par mot cl&eacute; ou ingr&eacute;dient. Des nouvelles recettes sont index&eacute;es automatiquement chaque jour.">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://glouton.ca">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="Glouton, les meilleures recettes du Qu&eacute;bec">
<meta property="og:description" content="Glouton est un moteur de recherche intelligent qui permet de trouver des recettes par mot cl&eacute; ou ingr&eacute;dient. Des nouvelles recettes sont index&eacute;es automatiquement chaque jour.">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://glouton.ca/site/images/social.png">
```

With that many errors in the file, no wonder their parser can't find the `og:image` correctly. You should check it out again in some time.